# Installing CUDA for Linux: Could NOT find CUDA

Tags: ubuntu, cuda

I want to install CUDA on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. So, I downloaded the .deb package from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads, which opened in Ubuntu Software Centre by default and then installed `cuda-repo-ubuntu1404`.

Now, I am trying to build another library which depends on CUDA, and in this case, I get the following error message:

```
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR not found or specified
-- Could NOT find CUDA (missing:  CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY)
```

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: I guess you only installed the repo configure, not the package itself. Try `apt-get update`, `apt-cache search cuda`, then install proper CUDA packages with `apt-get install package-names`.

Comment: The [linux getting started guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#abstract) has instructions.

Comment: Here on Ubuntu 16.04, this solved: `sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit` .

Answer (score 8):

I guess you only have installed the repo, not the packages. In order to install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

Then you have to set the environmental variables on the system (this is part of the [post-installation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions) tasks detailed on the CUDA toolkit documentation). There are many ways, but perhaps the simplest is to write them on your `~./bashrc`

**Extra: Building your library**

That should solve the problem of the CUDA libraries and driver installation, but if you are building your library manually on your system, perhaps you need to do some additional work; setting the needed paths before building your library.

You can do this exporting their values on your system before configuring the library, like:

```
export CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/cuda
./configure
```

or adding them manually on the configure file.

You must do that for the path variables you've listed, i.e.:

```
CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE 
CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS 
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR
```

You can find more information about environmental variables and how to set them [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: Just setting CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR should be sufficient. For instance: `set(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/cuda")`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `pytorch` v0.4.1 installation with `cuda9.2` on `Centos7` machine, setting `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR` did not work. Instead,

```
export CUDA_HOME=/<path>/cuda-9.2
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/<path>/cuda-9.2/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

worked well.